# Assigned "Selected" using a custom attribute

Tags: jquery, select

I have a very simple select with a custom options attribute:

```
    <select name='beverage' id='beverage'>
        <option value='0' desc='Tea'>Tea</option>
        <option value='1' desc='Coffee'>Coffee</option>
        <option value='2' desc= ‘Lemonade'>Lemonade</option>
    </select>
```

If I am passed a variable based on 'value', I can easily make the corresponding option "Selected" by thus:

```
    Var chosen = 1;
    $("#beverage").val( chosen ).attr('selected',true);
```

But if I am passed a var based on the 'desc' attr, like so:

```
    Var chosen = 'Coffee';
```

How do I make the selection? I have tried endless combinations like:

```
    ($("#beverage").attr( 'desc' = chosen )).attr('selected',true);
```

or

```
    ($("#beverage").attr( ['desc' = chosen] )).attr('selected',true);
```

and also tried using the filter option with no success.
Very frustrating as I know this is a simple problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be attr('selected', 'selected') ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attributes selector, but you have to target the option that has the attribute and not the select :

```
var chosen = 'Coffee';
$("#beverage option[desc='" + chosen + "']").prop('selected', true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EJALL/)

Note that `desc` is not a valid attribute, and you should be using `data-desc` instead.

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast! Thatnks heaps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#beverage[descr="chosen"]').attr('selected',true);
```